# Python 3.5x, 3.6x and 3.7x Install Fails on Windows 7 even with Universal C runtime updated

Tags: python

I have tried installing 3.5x, 3.6x and 3.7x on my windows 7 pro 64 bit OS with both the executable installer and the web based one from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ , I updated my Universal C runtime, restarted, uninstalled all previous versions, disabled my firewall in the event of the downloads being blocked, all return the same error, the setup freezes on 0%, then crashes with "i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80072f7d," in the log file. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try the follow tips:

1. Turn off your Antivirus then try the install again.
2. Clear your %temp% folder on your PC.
3. Try installing in Repair mode.

Comment: Thanks but none of the above worked :/ , windows defender is off, my avast is uninstalled, firewall is down, %temp% is empty, UAC is disabled, tried it in repair mode. Restarted, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I founded for this is uncheck the download of the debugging symbols and debug binaries